# Is there a way to list files recursively using Net::SFTP::Foreign?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to pull a list of all directories, sub-directories and files from a remote working directory using `Net::SFTP::Foreign`.

Currently, I'm using this line to pull a list of files on my SFTP site

```
my @newfilesLookedAtList = @{$sftp->ls(names_only => 1)}
```

It works fine, but it only shows me the directories. I need a list of the file names inside the directories.
I found this answer on the site - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32267575/5652660, which states I can use the following:

> $sftp->find(@paths, %opts) Does a recursive search over the given directory $path (or directories @path) and returns a list of the entries found or the total number of them on scalar context.
>
> Every entry is a reference to a hash with two keys: filename, the full path of the entry; and a, a Net::SFTP::Foreign::Attributes object containing file atime, mtime, permissions and size.

When I apply the above code:

```
my @newfilesLookedAtList = @{$sftp->find('/', names_only => 1)};
```

my file `@newfilesLookedAtList` returns empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign) POD states that `find` returns a **list**, which means that you should not try to dereference it.  Change:

```
my @newfilesLookedAtList = @{$sftp->find('/', names_only => 1)};
```

to:

```
my @newfilesLookedAtList = $sftp->find('/', names_only => 1);
```